# Why am I getting a DLL error when importing numba in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, numba

When I try (or another library tries) to import the 'numba' library I get the following error message: "DLL load failed while importing _typeconv: The specified module could not be found."

I have looked as deeply as I can in Google for similar occurrences and solutions. What I've found is only superficially similar and where solutions were even proposed they didn't work for me. At best I've come to the conclusion that I'm missing a particular DLL though I've no idea which one nor how to figure that out. Now I've got a Master's final project reliant on the usage of numba (indirectly, another third party library uses it) and I can't work around that.

I am using Python 3.8. It is the only Python installation on my Windows 10 machine (which is up-to-date as well). I am not using Anaconda nor am I willing to move to it at this point in time. I have installed numba on my system using "pip install numba" which gets the 0.49 version of numba.

After installing numba via pip, if I then start the Python CLI interface and attempt to import numba I get the following Traceback:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeconv\typeconv.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numba.core.typeconv import _typeconv
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _typeconv: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numba.misc.special import (
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\misc\special.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.core.typing.typeof import typeof
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .context import BaseContext, Context
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\context.py", line 11, in <module>
    from numba.core.typeconv import Conversion, rules
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeconv\rules.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .typeconv import TypeManager, TypeCastingRules
  File "C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeconv\typeconv.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg % (url, reportme, str(e), sys.executable))
ImportError: Numba could not be imported.
If you are seeing this message and are undertaking Numba development work, you may need to re-run:

python setup.py build_ext --inplace

(Also, please check the development set up guide http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/contributing.html.)

If you are not working on Numba development:

Please report the error message and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer
at: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new

If more help is needed please feel free to speak to the Numba core developers
directly at: https://gitter.im/numba/numba

Thanks in advance for your help in improving Numba!

The original error was: 'DLL load failed while importing _typeconv: The specified module could not be found.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If possible please include the following in your error report:

sys.executable: C:\Users\Luna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
```

### Update

When rolling back to numba 0.48 this issue ends up disappearing.

Comment: `_typeconv` is a c++ library. It sounds like it wasn't built before trying to import it. Did you get any error message from pip? Do you specifically need 0.49? 0.48.0 is the version you get from conda dated 27/01/2020.